# Using MEF, inject into an Import class

Tags: dependency-injection, mef

I have a logger interface that I inject into many different classes, can I inject that class in say a repository class, which is also an Import class which is injected into other classes?

Hope that makes sense, I'm a little confused by it myself.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a class can both import and export parts.

Glenn Block explains it well in his article [Managed Extensibility Framework: Building Composable Apps in .NET 4 with the Managed Extensibility Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx).